# Unable to print value of a label in a servlet

Tags: jsp, servlets

I want to get values of several labels that I have used in a web form. I'm using hidden input field to get this thing done, but I am unable to print the value of the label through a servlet as Im getting null as the value of the label

Following are the sample codes that I am using to test

index.jsp

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>JSP Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form name = "testform" action="submit" method = "post">
        <label> AgeoftheChild </label>
        <input type="hidden" name="lblage" value="AgeoftheChild">

        <input  type = "radio" name="age" value="10">10 <br>
        <input  type = "radio" name="age" value="20">20 <br>
        <input type = "radio" name="age" value="30">30 <br>

        <input type="submit" name="sub" value="submit">
    </form>     
</body>
```

This is the submit.java servlet

```
public class submit extends HttpServlet {


protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

    String age = request.getParameter("lblAge");

    try {
        /* TODO output your page here. You may use following sample code. */
        out.println("<!DOCTYPE html>");
        out.println("<html>");
        out.println("<head>");
        out.println("<title>Servlet NewServlet</title>");            
        out.println("</head>");
        out.println("<body>");
        out.println("<h1>Servlet NewServlet at " + age + "</h1>");
        out.println("</body>");
        out.println("</html>");
    } finally {
        out.close();
    }


}
```

}

I want to display AgeoftheChild
but the Output is null

Please help with with possible solutions

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first time you display the form, lblAge is null (still no form submit). Only after you submit the form lblAge will be filled.

```
if (request.getMethod().equalsIgnoreCase("POST")) {
    ...
```

*(IgnoreCase is a bit overdone.)*

Answer (score 1):

From your HTML page you are passing `lblage` and in your servlet you are taking it as `request.getParameter("lblAge");` 
So you need to change case of your label to get the value in servlet

```
`request.getParameter("lblage");`
```

In servlet need to implement the methods from `GenericServlet` or `HttpServlet` and then use request object to get the required parameter or attributes from request.

in your case use you need to implement `doPost` method.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the mistake. I have run the project after 'Clean and buid' but again I got the same thing :(

Comment: put `String age = request.getParameter("lblAge");` this line before `response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");` i.e. first line in your servlet and with the help of sop check value of age. change method to `doPost` edited in answer

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using `doPost` method of the HttpServlet ?